# Creating a sub-network on a different network

Tags: router, routing, troubleshooting, tunnel

I am on a network and am assigned 1 IP address for me. This is 172.16.1.202. However, I wanted to have multiple machines on at one time, so I created a router using a Raspberry Pi. It is running Raspbian Wheezy and is using ISC-DHCP server to handle the connections, hostap for the wireless broadcast, and IP tables for the routing. I followed the guide mostly at the adafruit guide [here](http://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/).

I am able to get wireless connections fine and it assigns each machine a valid IP address. They are able to talk to each other with no problems. They can also ping any machine on the 172 network. However, the machines on the 172 network cannot ping or even find the my 192 network. I assume this is ok if I only request data from another machine, as it seems to be able to get a successful ping meaning it knows how to return data to my machine, but it would not be ok if I wanted a 172 machine to push data to my machine.

How would I tell the 172 network or a machine that my IP address (172.16.1.202) can forward to my 192 network? Or am I going around this the wrong way? I can't mess with the 172 network itself or interfere with it, but I can change things on an individual machine on the 172 network.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Sadly, home networking questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be two different yet related problems here:

Problem #1:

Any time you have multiple machines hiding behind a single IP address, you need to use a networking feature called Port Address Translation (also known as NAT Overloading). This feature allows your router to dynamically re-map source ports of TCP traffic to outbound destinations and keep track of them, thereby transparently allowing return traffic to the unseen IPs behind it. That's a really simplified explanation, but you can find more information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

The following link is referenced in your original post, and contains instructions on Network Address Translation:
http://qcktech.blogspot.com/2012/08/raspberry-pi-as-router.html

Also, ensure that your DHCP server is handing out the IP of the "inside" interface for your clients as the default gateway. Example:

```
    subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.254;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    option domain-name "local";
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

Problem #2:

If you're not using Port Address Translation, your router is trying to pass traffic from the 192 network directly to the 172.16.1.x network directly - but the administrator of the 172.16.1.x network hasn't updated his configuration to tell his router to point traffic destined to "your" 192.-whatever network towards your IP (something that I'm guessing probably won't happen).

If you're using Port Address Translation, other machines on the 172.16.1.x network will not see automagically "see" machines on your 192.-whatever network because they're hidden - that's the way PAT works: it allows your private IPs to talk to each other, but also reach other networks through the Port Address Translation feature.

Good luck!

Comment: He's obviously using NAT or his machines wouldn't be able to talk to the 172 machines.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand what is happening a lot more now. Do you think there would be any way I could do this without changing the 172 side? The administrator doesn't want to be bothered with it.

Comment: Ricky: I missed that part. I blame the insomnia.